# Use Fenchel Duality to minimize cTx, subject to x ∈ A∩C

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

minimize cTx
subject to x ∈ A∩C,

￼where $x,c∈R^n$, C is a convex closed nonempty set in $R^n$,  A=a+S is an affine set, where $a∈R^n$ and S is a subspace of $R^n$, and A ∩ ri(C)≠ ∅.

Use the Fenchel duality theorem to show that the dual problem can be stated as

minimize aTy

subject to y−c ∈ S⊥

**In this question, what does the upside down "T" mean after the S in the final line of this question? Also, I am slightly unfamiliar with the format "cTx" and "aTy". Any help would be great.**

**This is the first question I've come across that asks for you to show that it is equivalent to a dual problem.**

Comment: $\perp$ means "perpendicular, orthogonal".

Comment: thank you! that makes sense now @SilviaGhinassi